# detect onchange event of country dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping, javascript, select

I am using select2 jQuery plugin to make Magento HTML select nicer. The plugin replaces the actual select with a set of tag which replicate the functionalities of the select. Doing in this way I am missing some default beahviour of Magento select, such as the switch between dropdowns countries and address input field when United States are selected.

Anyone knows where this functionalities are inside Magento js scripts?

Comment: Maybe you can use onchange='jsfn()' in the input.

Comment: but I don't know which is function is called when the country select changes

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I am researching how to fix this issue now.

Answer (score 2):

Code you are looking for is in `js/varien/form.js` file. Look for RegionUpdater = Class.create(); line, inside initialize function, you are probably interested in following line:

```
Event.observe(this.countryEl, 'change', this.update.bind(this));
```